# What Block Type for Left Column in Magento Theme?

Tags: magento

I'm working on a custom Magento (1.3) theme and am wanting to add a left column.

I've created template/page/html/left.phtml with the html in.

In 2columns-left.phtml, i've added the following:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left'); ?>
```

In page.xml, i've added the following:

```
<block type="page/html" name="left" as="left" template="page/html/left.phtml" />
```

What i'm not quite understanding is what that block type should be - it seems to work if I do page/html, core/template or page/html_header - what is this for and what is the correct value for this case, where I just want to effectively include a phtml file - page/html/left.phtml etc.

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: Fixed the code formatting.  If you indent your code on StackOverflow with a tab or four spaces, it wil automatically code-format/pretty-print.

Comment: @Alan - You've also added a semicolon where there wasn't one and didn't need to be. :-P

Comment: I'll take an extra semi-colon over default HTML formatted code ;)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip and fixing.

Comment: @ichilton - Please tick the best answer from available ones, if you have got your answer.

Answer (score 15):

This is a simplified version of what's going on, but will
hopefully be enough to get you going.

### Special Objects

There are three types of Objects that Magento considers "special".  These are Models, Blocks, and Helpers. Rather than use class names for these objects Magento uses URI-like strings called *class aliases* . So this

```
page/html
```

corresponds to the Block class

```
Mage_Page_Block_Html
```

Class here is referring to PHP classes, not CSS classes.

### Magento Page Rendering

A Layout Object is responsible for creating all the HTML for a Magento page.

A Layout Object is a collection of nested Block Objects.

Most Block Objects are Template Blocks, that is, the Block class inherits from the base Magento template block `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.  Template Blocks are objects responsible for rendering a phtml template file.

So, when you specify a "type" in the XML Layout files, you're telling Magento.

> I want to add a block object with the class foo/bar, using the template baz.phtml

In code, that's

```
<!-- "name" and "as" are used to identify the block in the layout, so that 
PHP code can get a reference to the object. -->
<block type="foo/bar" name="myname" as="myname" template="path/to/baz.phtml" />
```

If all you want to do is render a template file, you can use

```
type="core/template"
```

However, by using a different value, like

```
type="page/html"
```

your phtml template file gets access to all the methods in

```
Mage_Page_Block_Html
```

Which means you could do something like

```
File: template.phtml

<a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl();?>"></a>
```

The `core/template` class doesn't have a `getBaseUrl` method, but the `page/html` class does.

If you're doing custom module development (as opposed to just theming), I usually create a Block Object in my own module that extends one of the base Magento blocks.  This allows me to add my own methods to the block as I see fit.  If you're only theming, `page/html` is a decent default.

Comment: Thanks for going into such detail! - do you have any recommendations where is best to read up on that kind of stuff?

Comment: Based on what you said there, would it not be better to use core/template by default and move to page/html when you need to use methods like the one in your example?

Comment: 99% of the time you'll be creating HTML with your blocks, so having access to the methods never hurts, but it's a style/preference/judgment thing.  Nothing wrong with defaulting to  core/template.

Comment: ok, thanks. Is there any performance hit to having access to the methods though?

Comment: @Alan - From my view point, "Hats off" for your answer. Many many thanks for going into such details. Cleared some of my queries too.

Comment: @alan - thanks again for another great magento explanation / answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best type for this case is `core/text_list` because it concatenates every child HTML.

For testing you could use this example in your layout XML:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left">
  <block type="core/text" name="test">
    <action method="setText"><text>Hello World</text></action>
  </block>
</block>
```

Comment: Thanks - but it seems to dissapear if I change it to core/text_list?

Answer (score 0):

Block type for left column in magento theme

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left" translate="label">
    <label>Left Column</label>
</block>
```