# In Magento a new theme, new page layout, the header and footer work, but not the background. Why?

Tags: xml, templates, magento, layout, php

I'm completely new to this, and I just can't figure it out. Here is the code:

page.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/pd-1column.phtml">

            <!-- Add Styles to Head -->
            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/style.css</stylesheet></action>
            </block>

            <!-- Our Header -->
            <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header" translate="label">
                <label>Header</label>
            </block>


            <!-- Background -->
            <block type="page/html_background" name="background" as="background" translate="label">
                <label>Background</label>
            </block>

            <!-- The Footer -->
            <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
                <label>Footer</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </default>
</layout>
```

pd-1column.phtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head'); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header'); ?>      
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('background'); ?>      
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer'); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

File names:  header.phtml, background.phtml, footer.phtml

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:  The solution was to modify the page.xml file to

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="background" as="background" template="page/html/background.phtml">
            <label>Background</label>
 </block>
```

Comment: you should have class `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Background`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header" translate="label">
```

In this `page/html_header` type corresponds to block class file that exists in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php
```

This is core Magento block class.Each block type points to a particular class file.So your header template gets access to all these methods in `Header.php`

Similarly `Background.php` block doesn't exists in the path `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/`

Blocks are better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287226/what-block-type-for-left-column-in-magento-theme)

Comment: Thank you!  That explained enough to figure it out.  I have posted my revised code.

Comment: A related question.  In the xml file, why does header block have `translate="label"` and footer block have `template="page/html/footer.phtml"` ?