# Magento: include custom block in view.phtml

Tags: magento, block, php

I have created a block accrording to this tutorial: http://www.gravitywell.co.uk/blog/post/how-to-creating-your-own-custom-block-in-magento . Now I need to use my manufacturerblock.phtml on my pruduct view page (just somewhere closed to product description text).

In `local.xml` (under `<reference name="header">`) I added: (edit: I tried also under `<reference name="product.info">` in `<catalog_product_view>`

```
<block type="aimitmanufacturerblock/manufacturerblock" name="manufacturerblock" as="manufacturerblock" template="aimitmanufacturerblock/manufacturerblock.phtml" />
```

and I used `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('manufacturerblock')?>` in my `view.phtml`.

But it seems the phtml is not included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Apologies, I should have followed the link to the tutorial you gave first, I see it's all about creating a new block type!  However, I'll leave my answer for the moment - why do you need to create a new block type at all, there are loads of built in block types?.  This answer from Clockworkgeek could be useful to you too;

[Create a new Block in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378329/create-a-new-block-in-magento)

**Original answer;**

The issue is your block type - the block type isn't like a variable that you define yourself, there are specific built-in Magento block types which are used to instantiate the appropriate classes.  This SO thread will be useful to you for further explanation;

[Understanding Magento Block and Block Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633307/understanding-magento-block-and-block-type)

For another great explanation on block types read this one too;

[What Block Type for Left Column in Magento Theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287226/what-block-type-for-left-column-in-magento-theme)

Comment: Well I am trying to create an own module that will show a specific information about manufacturer including it's other products etc. So I assume that I need to have my own module with own block.

Comment: I know if I am creating a block using a specific custom template, and that block is displaying a list of products I would use `catalog/product_list` as the block type.

Comment: When I tried this, I get an error while loading the page. I use <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('manufacturerblock')?> for calling the block. Guess that's correct..?

Comment: Just thinking - is my local.xml record correct? <block type="aimitmanufacturerblock/manufacturerblock" name="manufacturerblock" as="manufacturerblock" template="aimitmanufacturerblock/manufacturerblock.phtml" /> I have the phtml file in folder \template\aimit\manufacturerblock\manufacturerblock.phtml

Comment: Got it working now!! My I had one more folder, which caused that it was not loaded! But thank you very much! Your post helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the block in `catalog/product/view.phtml`, you need to reference `product.info` in the `catalog_product_view` handle.
And I can just assume that the module is activated, the class alias is declared, the class is created and the cache is flushed

Comment: So do I understand correctly that I need to move this: <block type="aimitmanufacturerblock/manufacturerblock" name="manufacturerblock" as="manufacturerblock" template="aimitmanufacturerblock/manufacturerblock.phtml" /> just below <reference name="product.info"> in my local.xml? I did that now, but still doesn't show the echo from manufacturerblock.phtml. And your assumption is correct - I have activated module, class is declared correctly and cache is turned off.